# Shouldn't there be some adjustments for google cardboard?

Tags: setfocus

Shouldn't there be some adjustments for google cardboard? With all different sizes of phones and with everyone having a bit of differences in how far apart our eyes are I was looking for a way to re position the two images closer so that it looked better. I don't need to use all the pixels and I'm thinking if you allowed adjustments to the center placement of each view that this could be more usable. As is I have to hold the phone a bit further from me to see a good image.

Comment: The question as it stands snt fit for this site, as it as per title ask what should or shouldn't be in the google cardboard headset. I suggest an edit to something like "what can I do to solve the fixed lens-to phone distance problem in google cardboard", so that the question conforms to the sites rules. I answerd the qeustion as if it were phrased "what should I focus on when picking a headset to avoid the problems I had with google cardboard"

Answer (score 1):

The Cardboard is open "technology" and you are free to adjust it to your own personal needs - no one is going to do that for you. If you are on a bigger budget, there are cheap plastic headsets available from various manufacturers. I got my headset for around 35$ with shipping.

I personally use a [Color Cross](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00MO4DSEK) but there are many others. Just make sure to look for some with open back, so you can plug in headphones, for example, or use the camera once that becomes a thing. An adjustable phone holder is a big plus, so be on the lookout for that too.  Another important thing is adjustable IPD (Inter Pupillary Distance) for the lenses in the headset - some headsets with fixed lense distance gave me the cross-eyed effect. Also, many headsets have adjustable lens-to-phone distance, which also can be important.

Please note that all this is necessary for an okay-ish experience, and for the very best one available, you should get a whole integrated headset, like the Sony Morpherus, Oculus Rift or SteamVR. Also bear in mind that this technology is still in the RnD phase and there are many problems to be solved.

For an interesting read on some of these problems, check this out:
http://media.steampowered.com/apps/valve/2013/MAbrashGDC2013.pdf